# Can I simplify this with a prototype function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery prototypes. I do this same code many times:

```
   $message
        .removeClass()
        .addClass("message error")
        .show()
        .html('<li>' + json.Errors.join('</li><li>') + '</li>');
```

the variables here are the "error" and the html data. For success the addClass would be "message success".

Is there a way I could combine these four into one function and then just call the one and pass it success/error and the data?

Comment: What do you mean by "prototype function"? Adding stuff to `jQuery.fn`?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a jQuery function of your own is easy:

```
$.fn.showErrors = function() {
  return this.removeClass().addClass("message error").show()
    .html('<li>' + json.Errors.join('<li>'));
};
```

Then:

```
$message.showErrors();
```

Note that you don't really need the `</li>` closing tags.

In genera, a jQuery function added like that as a property of `$.fn` should expect `this` to refer to the current jQuery object. The function should return that value so that the normal chaining behavior of jQuery will work.  The one slightly confusing thing is that because `this` is *alread* a jQuery object, there's no need to wrap it again — no need to write `$(this)` in other words.

*edit* — sorry I've been away from the Internet for a bit (shocking!)  That code assumes that "json" is just floating around. It probably should be a parameter:

```
$.fn.showErrors = function(json) {
  return this.removeClass().addClass("message error").show()
    .html('<li>' + json.Errors.join('<li>'));
};
```

To call that:

```
$message.showErrors(json);
```

Comment: I do think `json` has to be passed, though, if the function is defined at the beginning (without any ajax context available).

Comment: As the OP has noted in the question, when there're no errors the class should be "message success".

Comment: @Pointy - How can I make this so that I pass in the type of message "success" or "error" and the message text?

Comment: Ah yes - sorry; I had an errand to run. I'll amend the answer @Marilou

Comment: @Marilou I'm not sure I understand your question about the "type" of the message.  The code posted in the original question suggests that "$message" is a jQuery reference to some element on the page.  It looks to me as if the message text comes from the JSON structure; without my knowing what that looks like, it's hard to say how to produce different messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.fn.updateErrors = function(errors) {
  var cssClass, errorsHtml;

  if(errors.length === 0) {
    cssClass   = "success";
    errorsHtml = "";
  } else {
    cssClass = "error";
    errorsHtml = "<li>" + errors.join("</li><li>") + "</li>";
  }

  return this.removeClass().addClass("message " + cssClass)
             .show().html(errorsHtml);
};
```

It will decide if the class should be 'error' or 'success' depending on whether the `errors` array is empty or not. Of course, if you logic is more complex than that, this function could be the home for that as well.

Usage:

```
$message.updateErrors(json.Errors);
```